# How do you implement a model built using sklearn pipeline in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pyspark, scikit-learn

I would like to use the model I built using sklearn pipeline in pyspark. The pipeline takes care of imputation, scaling and one-hot encoding and Random Forest Classification.I tried broadcasting the model and using pandas udf to predict.it did not work, got py4jjavaerror.

Comment: Hi! Can you add more detail like the complete error and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi ,I wont be able to do that because this code lives inside a remote server provided to me by my company, hence it would be a violation to do so. I'll try to add as much as details as possible though.